# SVN checkout browser

Tags: php, user-interface, svn, svn-checkout, working-copy

I've been looking all over for a SVN browser.  Now I'm *not* talking about anything like WebSVN or TRAC, I don't want to browse the repository; I want to browse the checkout.

I'm looking for a program that lets me browse the checkout (working copy) and shows me the info I'd normally need to SSH for.  So I could mark specific files or folders for some commit button, or see the status, or view a diff between the working and a prev version.  Basically a web GUI for a svn checkout.

A [windows] program that can let you work on a remote checkout as if it were local would also work.

Currently I have a checkout on my server running under dev.mysite.com.  I log in via ftp and edit and upload the files. I also keep SSH open so I can do a svn st to see what files I've worked on and to commit changes.  I want to work on the files on the same environment so I can't simply use a local checkout.  But I don't want to need to work via SSH.

Are there any apps such as I described?  Like a repo browser but for checkouts to do commits.  Like WebTortoiseSVN or such.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it could be easier to set up remote desktop then?

Comment: I find your terminology slightly confusing. It seems that you are looking for a graphical Subversion client that can handle working copies through SSH. Is that correct?

Comment: Remote desktop of a linux command line to windows, aka SSH....

I'm looking for a graphical Subversion client or webapp that can handle remote working copies in any manner.  Either a php webapp running on the server, or a win32 that can connect remotely.

Comment: when I say checkout I'm talking about a working copy.  Not a repository browser.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you SFTP-mount the remote site locally and use something like Tortoise SVN ( http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ ) to manage the SVN stuff locally?

For example you mount dev.yoursite.com as drive Z: and you can use it as a local drive. Tortoise SVN automatically finds that it holds a SVN checkout and you can use it transparently.

Comment: I have run into occasional trouble when trying to modify the mounted working copy like this, but to just browse for information it should work fine.

Comment: Well it's possible, because it depends on your internet connection. Also delays should be expected even for just browsing the "local" copy on the remote host.

Comment: I'll try the FTP mount, though with all of TortoiseSVNs disk access, I thought it might be slow.  TortoiseSVN doesn't allow the committing of multiple files in separate directories at once either.  I also tried webdav, but it can't be mounted in windows :(.

Comment: TortoiseSVN can commit multiple files in several directories as long as they are in the same checkout (e.g. all the folders are in trunk and are checked-out at the same time (hope you understand what i mean). If it bothers you that it's the root folder you cannot commit - try right clicking on free space in the folder (between files) and commit. This would commit the current directory (may be root directory). Also webdav is mountable on windows, google "mount webdav windows". The results are more than helpful.

Comment: I don't think TortoiseSVN can commit multiple specific individual files.  eg) /folderA/file1 and /folderB/file2 and /folderA/subfolderC/file3 and none of the other files.  You can't right click and select something like 'mark for commit'.

Comment: If, folderA and folderB are in the same SVN root, you can commit individual files. You can choose them on the commit dialog. If they are not in the same svn root (different repos,checkouts), you cannot commit them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the pecl package?

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php

It's an API for SVN, so it's not a GUI, but I'm sure you can build one on top.

*On a sidenote: your question is somewhat difficult to understand for me. I am not sure what you are really asking for, so if you could clearify some more, I might be able to add to my question.*

**EDIT** If you just need an SVN manager, then go with Tortoise (mentioned elsewhere) or consider using an IDE that has built-in SVN support, like Eclipse.

Comment: I have IDE's that have SVN support and I use TortoiseSVN lots.  But I want something where I can browse a remote working copy.  I figured a webapp running on the remote server would have been made already.  Like TRAC, but for working copies.  But it seems it hasn't been. So I might very well need to make my own.  Doesn't seem like it would be all that hard, just need to modify a PHP directory browser a little bit to include SVN data.

Comment: Just checked out that API, nice.  I was thinking that I would need to parse the raw data straight from command line if I did it myself.  That would really simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

As the checkout information is stored in the file system is there any reason that you cant mount the ftp directory as a local folder (or just browse to the ftp:// url) and use tortoise on it?